How to Install Java on a Mac (High Sierra 10.13)
How do you install Java for command-line use on a Mac running High Sierra 10.13?
Here's what I did:
1. Tried running java in the terminal, but was prompted to download the JDK first.
2. Downloaded the JDK from Oracle.
3. Ran java again, but it still didn’t work. I learned from Google that I needed to set up an environment variable.
4. Located javac by running: sudo find / -name javac
5. Added the path to .bash_profile.
6. Ran java again, but it failed because the system automatically appends bin to the path.
7. Modified .bash_profile to include:
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk/Contents/Home/"

8. Tried running java once more, but encountered this error:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin 
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libjli.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libjli.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
  
Abort trap: 6


I have no idea what to do next. Any advice?


The easiest way is to install homebrew and then you can do brew install openjdk@21 for the latest LTS version.

I tested this answer using a clean install of High Sierra 10.13.6. All updates from Apple were installed.
The downloads of the JDKs can be found at Java Downloads. I could not correctly view this site using Safari under High Sierra. Instead, I installed and used Firefox ESR (Extend Support Release). This link for Firefox download can be successfull viewed from Safari. The file I downloaded and installed was Firefox 115.16.1esr.dmg.
I tried JDK 23 by downloading and installing jdk-23_macos-x64_bin.dmg. This was not recognized by Java. Next, I tried JDK 21 by downloading and installing jdk-21_macos-x64_bin.dmg. This was recognized by Java.
Instructions for uninstalling a JDK can be found here. Personally, I just used the Finder to move the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk folder to the Trash.
I tested by using the simple code given below. The code was stored in the file named Simple.java.
class Simple{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
     System.out.println("Hello Java");  
    }  
}

Example of testing is given below.
dmas-Mac:Desktop dma$ javac Simple.java 
dmas-Mac:Desktop dma$ java Simple
Hello Java

BTW, I tested JDK 23 using macOS Monterey and did not encounter the problems that occurred with High Sierra.
